# Storing token(strtok) from function in array from main

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, strtok

I'm trying to make a function to split a sentence in words and store the words into an array of strings. If I use a global variable it works, the strings are stored nice and the job is done, however, when I try to pass an array defined in main it won't work.

```
void split(char sentence[], char *words[]){
  unsigned char n= 0;
  const char delim n= " ";
  char clone[strlen(sentence)];
  strcpy(clone, sentence);

  char *token;
  token= strtok(clone, delim);

  while(token != NULL){
    words[n++]= token;
    token= strtok(NULL, delim);
  }
  words[n]= NULL; //Needed for future usage of the array;
}

int main(){
  char *sentenceFromMain;
  sentenceFromMain= "A BB CCC DDDD";

  char *wordList[nrOfWords+1]; //I do have another function that counts words

  split(sentenceFromMain, wordList);
  exit(0);
}
```

If I do in the function, for example, `words[0]= "A";` it works.
Is token return a pointer? How should I get only whats stored in it? I tried multiple ways to do this, none of them worked well. Every response is welcomed!

Comment: You are passing a pointer to a *string literal*, however `strtok` writes to the string it is examining, and this is illegal.

Comment: @WeatherVane OP used _clone_.

Comment: `const char delim n= " ";` --> `const char *delim = " ";`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I see now thanks, but `clone` needs to be 1 character longer.

Comment: yes(however, we can not compile it. ), `char clone[strlen(sentence)];` --> `char clone[strlen(sentence)+1];` Also `clone` is local auto variable. Therefore points to that part are invalid outside the function.

Comment: I think the problem was solved. `clone` needed a +1 length, thanks, @BLUEPIXY and @Weather Vane. With `*delim` it won't compile. I also edited, I wrote argument instead of token by mistake, sorry for that!

Comment: As long as you keep this line `words[n++]= token;` the problem is not solved. As @Some_programmer_dude pointed out, you store pointers to memory in `word` that is not valid after you leave the function.

Comment: @Gerhardh, I can make a clone inside main, but how can I replace what's inside it every time the user is entering another sentence?

Comment: @Cooble, if you need to keep the content after the function returns, you must malloc some new memory for every word.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `strtok` returns pointers into the string it tokenizes. The pointers you get will be pointers into the `clone` array, which is local inside the `split` function. Once the `split` function returns the pointers will no longer be valid.

One possible way to solve this problem is to not have a local `clone` array, but have it externally outside the function, and pass it in as the first argument and use that argument in the call to `strtok`.

Comment: This could be a solution, but I will need this function multiple times across my program. Should I just put the clone in main? If I do that, how should I override it every time I need to change it?